# Fulltext searching array of strings

Tags: php, full-text-search

I have a PHP array of strings: ie: "Big green car parked outside"..etc

I would like to perform boolean search operations on these strings, similar to MySQL fulltext searching , or Sphinx Searching.

For example, I would like to find all strings containing word "green" but not "car"

Does anyone know of any existing PHP classes or libraries which would help me accomplish this ? Or can anyone suggest any google terms I could search for ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to have support for operators (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP function `array_filter()` will do the trick here.

```
function greennotcar($v)
{
    if(strpos($v, " green ") === false)
        return false
    if(strpos($v, " car ") !== false)
        return false
    return true
}

$newarray = array_filter($array, "greennotcar");
```

This checks if the string contains `green`, if it doesn't, exclude it from the array. Then, it checks if it contains `car`, if it does, exclude it. Otherwise, include it.

EDIT: I added spaces in the strings so you wouldn't match cart as well as car, for example. This is all up to your own preference.

Answer (score 1):

double `preg_match()` function may be help you?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any existing standalone solution that can work directly with variables. You could code your own implementation using [PCRE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php), [str_word_count](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) and other string/array functions. The resources are there. Inspiration may come as well from the approaches taken in some open source apps, like [Dokuwiki's full-text search functions](http://github.com/splitbrain/dokuwiki/blob/master/inc/fulltext.php).

A more powerful solution (including an indexing process) could be [Zend_Search_Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html):

> Zend_Search_Lucene is a general
>   purpose text search engine written
>   entirely in PHP 5. Since it stores its
>   index on the filesystem and does not
>   require a database server, it can add
>   search capabilities to almost any
>   PHP-driven website. Zend_Search_Lucene
>   supports the following features:
>
> - Ranked searching - best results returned first
> - Many powerful query types: phrase queries, boolean queries, 
>     wildcard queries, proximity queries,
>     range queries and many others.
> - Search by specific field (e.g., title, author, contents)